# Set FTP as SVN server repository path

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, visualsvn-server

I have external hosting but didn't support installing SVN server application, I installed on my local computer Visual SVN server, and tried to set it's repository as ftp path, The application did't support network ftp, I tried to map ftp path to drive letter but didn't succeeded.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What made you think that will work? FTP is not one of the supported access methods for SVN.

While mapping a drive letter, and using file:// URLs MIGHT work, especially if you are the only person using it and you only ever use one computer to access it, it is not recommended to use file:// access to a repository on a drive share, as it can cause repository corruption.

To host a SVN repository properly you will need the ability to run processes on the host machine, or use one of the many readily available public hosting providers, like sourceforge, Google Code, Github, etc.

Comment: Mapped network drive can't be used as repo root location. UNC paths only (i.e. `//share/repos`).